# Django: How to access object id with the reverse relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have this code:

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField("Item", on_delete=CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    # ...
```

`Recipe` objects do have an `item_id` attribute, but Item objects don't have a `recipe_id` attribute. Is there a way to allow both models to directly access the id of the other side of the relation?

- Note that for some external reasons (that are not interesting to explain here), I can't access fields by relations, so `recipe.id` is unavailable to me.
- Of course, a workaround could be to define a property named `recipe_id` on the `Item` object, it works but feels unnatural to me, and a bit repetitive since I need do to it on multiple models:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    @property
    def recipe_id(self) -> Optional[int]:
        if self.recipe:
            return self.recipe.id
```

Comment: You can access it with `myitem.recipe.id` (wrapped in a `try`-`except AttributeError`. It also does not make much sense that an `Item` should have a `recipe_id`, since your `OneToOneField` means that each `Recipe` has *one unique* `Item`, but it does not mean that all `Item`s are linked to a `Recipe` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks. As I said in the first point, I can span lookups so `myitem.recipe.id` is unfortunately not an option to me at the moment. The sense of the current relationships is exactly what I want to. I'd expect to have `None` result if there is no reverse relation, as simulated in the property I use as a workaround (cf. my updated question). But I guess with your answer that there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to **One-to-one relationships** in this documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

As it states **If you define a OneToOneField on your model, instances of that model will have access to the related object via an attribute of the model.**

**For reverse queries, The related model in a one-to-one relationship also has access to a Manager object, but that Manager represents a single object, rather than a collection of objects**

you can access the item_id from recipe as  `Recipe.objects.get(pk=1).item.id`

access recipe_id from item as `Item.objects.get(pk=2).recipe.id`

But if the recipe id is not present (not mapped) it will raise `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error. which you can enclose in a try except block.

```
 try:
    Item.objects.get(pk=2).recipe.id
 except:
   return None
```